# How to read fingerprint and get image as input?

Tags: swing, image-processing, fingerprint

I want read fingerprints in my application and save the pattern as images. How can I do it? what SDK should I prefer? and how can I read the fingerprint and get it as input? please help me with details

Comment: Fingerprint from Keyboards? No right? Obviously you'd say no fingerprints from a fingerprint reader. Good, those come with their SDK for various languages :)

Comment: what should i do with this sdk?

Comment: Use it and code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Readers come with thier SDK for various languages . [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97590/A-Framework-in-C-for-Fingerprint-Verification) an article about A Framework for Fingerprint Verification.